# How to define a variable in a makefile and then use it within Fortran code

Tags: variables, makefile, fortran, conditional-compilation

I am trying to define a variable in a makefile, and then depending on whether that variable is set, change which code block is compiled in my Fortran routine.

Simple example I can't get working:

```
program test
    implicit none
    integer :: a
#ifdef MYVAR
    a = 1
#else
    a = 0
#endif
    write(*,*) a
end program test
```

My makefile is:

```
MYVAR=1
all:
    ifort temp.F90 -fpp
    echo $(MYVAR)
```

The `echo $(MYVAR)` line correctly prints 1. However, when the test program is compiled it sets a=0. How do I get the Fortran code to recognize MYVAR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an extra flag

```
OPTIONS = -DMYVAR=$(MYVAR)
```

and then you compile it with

```
all:
    ifort $(OPTIONS) <file.f90> -fpp
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: Great! I used a combination of yours and Alexander's. Thanks for the fast responses.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the variable at compile time (in your Makefile) using `-D`:

```
all:
    ifort -DMYVAR=1 temp.F90 -fpp
    echo $(MYVAR)
```

Or, since you just check whether it is defined or not:

```
all:
    ifort -DMYVAR temp.F90 -fpp
    echo $(MYVAR)
```

Comment: Great! I used a combination of yours and Kyles's. Thanks for the fast responses.